# Синонимизировать метки [scroll] и [прокрутка]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Надо синонимизировать метки (у обеих есть описание, и в этих описаниях они явно ссылаются друг на друга).

- [scroll](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scroll) (528 вопросов)
- [прокрутка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) (66 вопросов)

Основная — [прокрутка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0), так как она на русском.

Comment: Вообще-то есть элемент управления `scroll`. Я бы не ставил на вопрос по нему метку [прокрутка]...

Comment: @Глеб почему? разве scroll не относится к прокрутке? элемент — это, скорее всё таки, scrollbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 511 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 528 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 507 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'scroll': [scroll] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 573
tag remapping of [прокрутка] and [scroll] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
7 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
4 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym scroll -> прокрутка was approved!
```